# Qt program fails to run

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm starting to learn c++ gui and thought I would create the first gui program but it doesn't seem to run. I created a project and edited it in Qt designer. When I attempt to run it, qtmake.exe ask permissions to use internet access through my firewall which I allow. As soon as that happens, in the right lower corner of the screen a build progress bar pops up and progress is at 50%. Then everything freezes.

When I attempted to click the start debugging instead of run, after 40 seconds a message pops up stating that the progress toke longer than expected and I can chose either to give GDB more time or stop debugging. If I choose to continue, nothing happens.

I also tried

build > run qmake

build > rebuild project "test"

which ran successfully.

I then went to the release folder of the project and double clicked test.exe (28k). In Windows task manager, 3 copies of test.exe were created. Each is 112k in size. For 30 minutes the application didn't start while the mouse cursor seemed to be loading. Then the size of the 3 copies of test.exe in Windows task manager started to change in size from 112 to 56 to 60.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When I was making a Qt project I've been experiencing some of these weird behaviors as well. Running the Q-make and fully rebuilding the project mostly did the job.